# Split unit Air Conditioner replace compressor single to three phase

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, compressor

I have a 3-ton split AC "single-phase compressor" was working perfectly until I moved it to another location, some oil spilled from the suction pipe during the transportation so when I installed it in the new location I added 900Ml of oil "I know it was a wrong thing to do" I was too lazy to the cut the compressor pipes out and drain the oil from the compressor to add the exact amount of oil which is 1100Ml, anyway when I charged it with refrigerant the amount to fill the unit is 2L "Written on the outside unit" I barely added 1L and the pressure on the suction side was 5 Bar "Which is the recommended pressure on the suction side when it's fully charged" it wasn't very long within 3 minutes and the switch burned and the breaker tripped.

I then cut the compressor pipes out and drained the oil it was almost double the amount of what it's recommended and the suction valve seemed to be damaged from heat, I couldn't find parts for the compressor, so my friend told me he has a 3-ton compressor he doesn't want it "FOC" but it's a three-phase compressor and my compressor is single-phase.

**My question can I replace a single-phase compressor with a three-phase compressor on my split unit or do I need an adapter or something like that? Because the voltage for the three-phase is 460v and the single-phase is 220v.**

My single-phase compressor name is HERMETIC COMPRESSOR AW 5542E, the three-phase is a scroll compressor ZR42K3-TFD.

Comment: Do you have 460V 3-phase on the site?

Comment: Since the majority of homes in the US use 120/208 single phase service, the answer is a no.  You would need to call your local power company to upgrade the drop to your house to 480 3 phase.

Comment: It’s not only the voltage but the 3 phase. There are drives out there than can convert single phase into 3 phase, I just purchased a Yaskawa to do this for one of our buildings that only had single phase 240.  With this said the drive works great but costs as much as a new compressor would and the 20hp drive needed a 100 amp breaker so the draw on a panel can also be an issue. The drive was called a single phase converter.

Comment: Thank you guys as Ed Beal said I need a very expensive inverter to do that, I'll probably buy a new single-phase compressor.

Comment: @Harper Yes, I do have 3 phase power in my house.